# I cannot use the result of a custom hooks in a function or inside an effect hooks

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I created a custom hook that allows me to return a list of people

- File: **persons.hooks.ts**

```
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import Person from "../../models/person/Person";

const usePersons = () => {
    const [persons, setPersons] = useState<Array<Person>>([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setPersons([
            {id: 1, fullName: "Andrew Jones", createdAt: new Date(2001, 5, 12), bornAt: new Date(2002921)},
            {id: 2, fullName: "Williams Hope", createdAt: new Date(2020, 8, 13), bornAt: new Date(2002420)},
            {id: 3, fullName: "Markus Denzel", createdAt: new Date(2020, 8, 13), bornAt: new Date(2002420)},
            {id: 4, fullName: "John Lewis", createdAt: new Date(2020, 8, 13), bornAt: new Date(2002420)},
            {id: 5, fullName: "Abraham Lincoln", createdAt: new Date(2010, 0, 15), bornAt: new Date(2002420)},
            {id: 6, fullName: "Jack Bauer", createdAt: new Date(2020, 8, 13), bornAt: new Date(2002420)},
            {id: 7, fullName: "Sarah Watson", createdAt: new Date(2020, 8, 13), bornAt: new Date(2002420)}
        ]);
    }, []);
    return persons;
};

export default usePersons;
```

I created another custom hook that returns a person whose id is passed as a parameter

- File: **person.hooks.ts**

```
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import Person from "../../models/person/Person";
import usePersons from "./persons.hooks";

const usePerson = (id: string) => {
    const [person, setPerson] = useState<Person|null>(null);
    const persons = usePersons();

    useEffect(() => {
        persons.forEach(person => {
            if (person.id) {
                if (person.id.toString() === id.toString()) {
                    setPerson(person);
                }
            }
        });
    }, [id]);

    return person;
};

export default usePerson;
```

I then created a page that allows me to display the fields of a given person

- File: **person-detail.tsx**

```
import React, {FunctionComponent, useEffect, useState} from "react";
import { RouteComponentProps } from "react-router-dom";
import usePerson from "../../hooks/person/person.hooks";

type Params = {id: string};

const PersonDetail: FunctionComponent<RouteComponentProps<Params>> = ({match, history}) => {
    const person = usePerson(match.params.id);
    const handleGoBack = () => {
        history.replace('/persons');
    };
    return (
        <div>
            {console.log(person)}
            <h2>{person?.fullName}</h2>
            <button onClick={handleGoBack} className="btn btn-primary">Return to list</button>
        </div>
    );
};

export default PersonDetail;
```

> {console.log (person)} gives me the null value. So nothing to display.
> I don't understand what happened.

Comment: In the **person.hooks.ts** file, when I put console.log (persons) outside of useEffect, I get a result: **(7) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]** in console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function hook `usePersons`. In first call, it return null, because `useEffect` in `usePersons` will be executed after it return null. The same with, `useEffect` of `usePerson`, first call, `list persons` will be empty. I think `useEffect` of `usePerson` should depend on `persons`. Let try:

```
const usePerson = (id: string) => {
    const [person, setPerson] = useState<Person|null>(null);
    const persons = usePersons();

    useEffect(() => {
        persons.forEach(person => {
            if (person.id) {
                if (person.id.toString() === id.toString()) {
                    setPerson(person);
                }
            }
        });
    }, [id, persons]);

    return person;
};
```